# Consecutive transactions

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to simulate a situation where two users (on seperate devices) both run a `Transaction` at the same time. To imitate this, I made a `List<String>` of strings which would be added to the database without a delay between them.
However, only the first item in the `List` was added to the database, the second never arrived. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to have both items added to the database.

The call to the Transaction happens in the code below, along with the creation of the list:

```
List<String> items = new List<String>();
items.add("A test String 1");
items.add("A test String 2");

for (String q in questions)
{
    database.updateDoc( q );
}
```

The code I use for updating the data in my database:

```
  void updateDoc( String item ) async
  {
    var data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['item'] = item;

    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {

      /// Generate a unique ID
      String uniqueID = await _generateUniqueQuestionCode();


      /// Update existing list
      DocumentReference docRef = Firestore.instance
                  .collection("questions")
                  .document("questionList");

      List<String> questions;
      await transaction.get(docRef)
            .then (
              (document) {
                /// Convert List<dynamic> to List<String>
                List<dynamic> existing = document.data['questions'];
                questions = existing.cast<String>().toList();

              }
            );

      if ( ! questions.contains(uniqueID) )
      {
        questions.add( uniqueID );
        var newData = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        newData['questions'] = questions;

        transaction.set(docRef, newData );
      }


      /// Save question
      docRef = Firestore.instance
                .collection("questions")
                .document( uniqueID );
      transaction.set(docRef, data);
    });
  }
```

In reality, I have a few fields in the document I'm saving but they would only complicate the code.
I keep track of a list of documents because I need to be able to retreive a random document from the database.

When executing the first code snippet, only the first item in the list will be added to the database and to the list that keeps track of the documents.
No error is thrown in the debug screen.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you need to await the call to updateDoc to make sure they all happen in the order you specify?

Comment: I would think not. The order shouldn't matter as I was trying to simulate a situation where two users try to run `updateDoc` at the same time

Comment: Please edit the question to state exactly what you are trying to accomplish here.  That's not a typical use case for a single app instance.  If you're trying to find out if transactions work, be assured that they do.  They're meant to defend against cases where multiple apps or processes are making changes to a document, not a single app instance.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the pointer, I'm on it.

Comment: Would the ´Transaction` work differently if several devices are making changes simultaneously? In that case, my test is invalid.

Comment: The way the Firestore SDK works is that it keeps a single connection open and pipelines each request through that connection.  When there are multiple clients, you have multiple connection, and each request can hit the service at a different time.  I'd suspect that what you're trying to simulate isn't really close to the real thing.

Comment: Okay, that settles it. I had no idea how transactions worked in that much detail as the documentation didn't go that deep.
Thank you so much for your help and insight, have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) in the comments under my question:

> That's not a typical use case for a single app instance. If you're
>   trying to find out if transactions work, be assured that they do.
>   They're meant to defend against cases where multiple apps or processes
>   are making changes to a document, not a single app instance.

And also:

> The way the Firestore SDK works is that it keeps a single connection
>   open and pipelines each request through that connection. When there
>   are multiple clients, you have multiple connection, and each request
>   can hit the service at a different time. I'd suspect that what you're
>   trying to simulate isn't really close to the real thing.